# How do I get the children of a frame node?

Tags: python, scripting, node-editor

I need to get the child of a frame node but it seems it is not possible "simply".
I'll have to create a function myself or have I missed something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of looking at the frame node and trying to find its *children* you have to look at each node and see what its *parent* is:

```
import bpy

children = []
nodes = bpy.context.scene.node_tree.nodes
frameNode = nodes['Frame']

for node in nodes:
    if node.parent == frameNode:  
        children.append(node)

print(children)
```

This creates a list of the frame node's children.

Or the more condensed version:

```
import bpy

nodes = bpy.context.scene.node_tree.nodes
frameNode = nodes['Frame']
children = [node for node in nodes if node.parent == frameNode]
```

This is based on *compositor nodes* so accessing the node tree will be slightly different for materials, but the same logic will apply.

Comment: Indeed, it also works well with materials. Thank you very much.